Can Mathematica be forced to include initial zero terms in series expansions?
This is not an emergency or even an urgent question, but it would be convenient, when I'm comparing manual and computed results, if Series[] reported zero-order terms that evaluate to zero.
Example: Series[Log[1 + x], {x, 0, 5}] returns

SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 
Rational[-1, 2], 
Rational[1, 3], 
Rational[-1, 4], 
Rational[1, 5]}, 1, 6, 1]

Now, I can recover the initial zero of the representing polynomial with SeriesCoefficient[%, 0] or the entire coefficient list with CoefficientList[Series[Log[1 + x], {x, 0, 5}], x], which gives:
{0, 1, -(1/2), 1/3, -(1/4), 1/5}

I assume that one way to get Series[] output to match CoefficientList[] would be to override Series[] by adding an Option, but that's likely above my expertise level.  Is there a hack out there, or advice on how to proceed?

There is no straightforward way to get the SeriesData result to be SeriesData[x,0,{0,1,-1/2,1/3,-1/4,1/5},0,6,1]; for a validated SeriesData object the lead coefficient must be nonzero. So I'd say using CoefficientList is already the hack you seek, or at least a reasonable one among perhaps several.

If you gave an example of a comparison that you would like to make, you might get useful suggestions that avoid this problem.

What about zero terms in the middle? Ex. Series[Log[1 + x^2], {x, 0, 7}]

Here's a hacky way (probably best for display purposes only):
ClearAll[heldZero];
Format[heldZero] = 0;
N[heldZero, _] = 0;
heldZero /: heldZero + x_ := x;
heldZero /: heldZero*x_ := heldZero;
heldZero /: heldZero^p_?Positive := heldZero;

ser = Series[Log[1 + x^2], {x, 0, 10}];
fullser = 
  ReplacePart[
   ser, {3 -> CoefficientList[ser, x] /. 0 -> heldZero, 4 -> 0, 
    6 -> 1}];



Thanks all for the comments and thanks Michael E2 for the code.  I'll try it out!

Tried several inputs. The code works on the SeriesData output object.  Normal[] does zap the zero (no surprise).  Thanks again.

@TomBarson You're welcome. If you omit the algebraic rules (which begin heldZero /:...), the zero terms remain after Normal[[]. You can then convert to the regular form for further calculation with fullser /. heldZero -> 0. The rules allow heldZero to behave like zero in algebraic operations with SeriesData[] objects. Without them, heldZero behaves like an undefined symbol but is displayed as 0, which I thought a bit confusing when I tried fullser^2; so I added the rules. You can always map heldZero -> 0, do the algebra, and fill in the coefficients with heldZero as above.

Thanks again.  Lots to explore in the M series stuff.
